# Will setting $/="\R" allow chomp() to work correctly with most files in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, newline

Does anyone know for sure if setting `$/="\R";` will reliably let chomp() do the correct thing, that is remove whatever end-of-line conventions are on a line?

Specifically, I run scripts on Windows and UNIX and have to process files that come off of the net, and have unknown end-of-line conventions: MS-DOS, UNIX, MacOS < 9, whatever.

I recently stumbled on "\R", but I hadn't seen it before.  I think it's new.  Well, newer than Perl 5.006. (It's been a while.)

The "\R" claims to do Unicode newlines, as well.  I have no way to test this correctly.

Thanks.

-Erik

I was surprised to learn there's actually a "newline" tag in  *stackoverflow*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will setting $/='\R' allow chomp() to work correctly with most files in perl?

Setting `$/` to `'\R'` will consider the two-character sequence `"\\R"` as newline.
Setting `$/` to `"\R"` will result in a warning about an `Unrecognized escape`.

`\R` is not a string but has a meaning only in the context of regular expressions. But the documentation for `$/` clearly states:

> Remember: the value of `$/` is a string, not a regex.  awk has to be better for something. :-)

Comment: Rats.  I suppose there is a perl module to do it, someplace.  Any favorites?

Comment: @ErikBennett: Your original question was answered and your last comment asks a new question. Apart from that, why not just use `s{\R\z}{}` instead of `chomp` since all you want to do is to strip a potential newline at the end.

Comment: @Erik: Remember that the line terminator (along with any trailing space) will be removed anyway if you're do `split ' ', $_`. You can also use `s/\s+\z//` instead of `chomp` if trailing whitespace of any sort is insignificant. Finally, you can install [`PerlIO::eol`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::eol) which will allow you to do `open my $fh, '<:raw:eol(LF)', $file` after which *all* line endings will appear as a simple `LF` in the input stream. Clearly the line terminator for output files must be explicitly selected.

Comment: As @Steffen points out, my original question was answered.  I just end up with all sorts of nutty files, like DOS files that terminate with a ctrl-z and no newline of any sort at the end of the final line.  I like @Steffen's `s{\R\z}{}` notation.

Comment: @Erik: You asked for alternatives (specifically a module) so I suggested three ways. And if your output files are missing line terminators altogether then it's simply that you've removed them with `chomp` (or whatever) and not put them back on output. Cetainly `s/\R\z//` won't make them magically reappear.

Comment: @Borodin:  Yes, thank you.  I'll look at `PerlIO::eol`.  I don't want anything to reappear.  I just get a lot of weird files from all over the place as input.  All of my output is crisp, clear UNIX newlines.  I don't even know how these ctrl-z files get created.  `edlin`, maybe?  It doesn't happen often.  Anyway, thanks to everyone for the quick answers.

Comment: @Erik: The DOS Ctrl-Z end-of-file marker shouldn't be included in the on-disk file size. It's no longer necessary because Windows now keeps track of the size of the file in the directory entry, in the same way as Linux, so if you're seeing Ctrl-Z in your input data then it's either a bug or part of the data. I'm sorry if you feel I'm going on after your problem has been resolved, but it seems clear that there is more to this than line endings. All systems will write text files with no line terminator after the last line; it should make no difference if you're using the equivalent of `chomp`.

Comment: Re "*why not just use `s{\R\z}{}` instead of `chomp`*",  Why not just use `s{\s+\z}{}` instead of `chomp`. If your format has significant trailing whitespace, something's gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I created [`Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp`](https://metacpan.org/release/MOB/Acme-InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp-0.04) a while ago as a joke, but it does provide a workaround for the restriction that `$/` cannot be a regular expression. With version 0.04 (just uploaded), you can say

```
use Acme::InputRecordSeparatorIsRegexp ':all';

open my $fh, '<:irs(\R)', 'file-with-ambiguous-line-endings.txt';
autochomp($fh,1);     # or (tied *$fh)->autochomp(1)
@lines = <$fh>;
...
```